# Graphviz special characters

Tags: java, graphviz

Could someone guide me how to construct

MV-123-1.3.2-23423GF

kind of strings using Graphviz API ?

Its creating separate circles for each token after -

```
    GraphViz gv = new GraphViz();
  gv.addln(gv.start_graph());
  gv.addln("1.0 -> MV-123-1.3.2-23423GF [color=red];");
  gv.addln("MV-123-1.3.2-23423GF  -> 1.2 [color=red];");
  gv.addln("1.2 -> 1.3 [color=red];");
  gv.addln("1.3 -> 2.0;");
  gv.addln("2.0 -> 3.0;");
  gv.addln("3.0 -> 3.1;");
  gv.addln("1.0 -> 2.0;");
  gv.addln("1.1 -> 1.3;");
  gv.addln("2.5 -> 2.6;");
  gv.addln("2.6 -> 3.0 [splines=false];");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To keep this as a single token, it needs double quotes around it. These have to be inserted
as escaped characters in java:

```
gv.addln("1.0 -> \"MV-123-1.3.2-23423GF\" [color=red];");
```